# C# Using Custom class in a List

Tags: c#, list

I have a class and I am using it inside a LIST

```
List<user> listWithCustomClass = List<user>();
```

myClass.cs

```
public class user
{
        public user(string fullname, string city, string state, int age, int type)
        {
            name = fullname;
            citi = city;
            estate = state;
            tipe = type;
        }

        private string name = string.Empty;
        private string citi = string.Empty;
        private string estate = string.Empty;
        private int tipe = 0;

        public string getFullname
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value;}
        }

        public string getCity
        {
            get { return citi; }
            set { citi = value;}
        }

        public string getState
        {
            get { return state; }
            set { state = value;}
        }

        public int getType
        {
            get { return type; }
            set { type = value;}
        }
}
```

How can I add a custom toString() without having to override generic toString(). I would like to add something like showDate().

For example, in a combobox I would like the output of the inserted information to be:

--> Hello, your name is **{name}** and your age is **{age}**

Like this:

```
 foreach(var item in user)
        {
            user.ShowData();
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking.  You can just implement that method in your class.  Have you tried?  Also I assume you meant `item.ShowData();`, not `user.ShowData();`.

Comment: @juharr I think he is asking how to use such a method in something like a combo box, which typically just calls `ToString`. Part of the answer will rely on what display tech is being used.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET you're correct.

Comment: So.... which display tech are you using; each tech (and control) can have slightly different ways of accomplishing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your class:

```
public string ShowData()
{
     return "Hello, your name is " + name + " and your age is " + age.ToString();
}
```

but you must also define `age` first. Which, following your style, would be:

```
private int age = 0;
```

and then in the constructor add:

```
this.age = age;
```

**EDIT**

```
foreach(var item in listWithCustomClass)
        {
            item.ShowData();
        }
```

Comment: But how can I loop between all list items ??? That I'm having trouble. For each item in the list I want you to add inside the combobox according to the method ShowData ()

Comment: @KenSoares See my update. It's like you had but modified a bit.